# In VS08, On F5, sometimes WCF service loaded correctly, sometimes I get a list of files

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Sorry, but I am not sure what causes the problem, and the problem isn't happening right now. I'll have to describe from memory.

So I've started creating WCF Service Applications.  Sometimes, when press F5 to run the project I get the correct screen, a screen that says:

### Service1 Service

```
You have created a Service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
```

and so on and so on.  But after I've done a little editing, sometimes I will run the project again, and the browser, instead of loading the above screen, will show me the directory containing the files.

What is going on?  How can I fix(?) the problem and prevent it from happening again?

Comment: The problem only occurs when I am demoing the WCF to my boss, or when I am trying to post the issue to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the .svc file and "Set as start page".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Microsoft keyboard?

I have this same problem from time to time and finally realized I was hitting the F Lock key above the Backspace key on occasion. That toggles the F5 key to an "Open" command.

Freaked me out until I figured it out.

Give it a shot and see if that is it.

jeffa

Comment: sorry, nope. I had this problem happen to me once on my laptop, and now here on my desktop.  Firefox still loads up a page, but instead of loading the svc file, it just shows the directory.